# iOS today extension not showing

Tags: ios, today-extension

I'm developing a today extension and it works fine on simulator, but when I run my app on device it doesn't work. App works fine but extension it doesn't show so that I can add it to drop down with other extensions(like it doesn't exists). Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: How could anyone possibly advise you when you show no code, or what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check if extension deployment target is compatible with your device

Comment: Thank you, extension was 8.2 while device 8.1

Comment: Omh! They may at least add warning! The hosting app and extension has different deployment target and it silently skipped. Or at least make default target == hosting app current target...

Comment: If you're using a FrameWork to share code with your app, also make sure the Framework Kit is targeting the right OS!!!  Creating them at the same time will also cause the FrameWork to be the wrong target just like the extension was.

Comment: EXACTLY! Extension deployment target must much Containing App deployment target in General pane in Project Settings

Comment: In my case, the deployment target was right but it still wasn't showing up. I had to change devices from `Universal` to `iPhone` as that matches the devices supported by my main application